# Non-trivial graph automorphism groups with $D_n$ as subgroup

Tags: graph-theory, symmetric-groups, algebraic-graph-theory, dihedral-groups, graph-isomorphism

I understand that the automorphism group of an $n$ cycle graph is the dihedral group $D_n$ of order $2 n$. From the comment of @Christian, I also understand that $S_n$ is the automorphism group of the complete graph $K_n$ which has $D_n$.

Other than these two obvious cases, I would like to know what are the other known automorphism groups of graphs which have $D_n$ as a subgroup.
Of course, the easiest are the graphs which have multiple $n$ cycle graphs as subgraphs or multiple $K_n$ as subgraphs. But, are there other graphs?

Comment: The complete graph with $n$ vertices has the full symmetric group $S_n$ as its automorphism group, which of course has $D_n$ as subgroup.

Comment: @ChristianSievers, I should've noticed that earlier. I am trying to find non-trivial cases. Should I edit this question or create a new one?

Comment: I don't know. I see no problems editing this.

Comment: As you may know, every finite group can be realized as the automorphism group of a graph. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frucht%27s_theorem

Comment: @GerryMyerson, yes, that's Frucht's theorem. So, what I would like to know   whether there are well known classes of graphs whose automorphism groups contain $D_n$ as subgroup.

Comment: Pick any group $G$ that has a subgroup isomorphic to $D_8$ (for example, $C_2\times D_8$, where $C_2$ is cyclic of order 2), use the proof of Frucht to construct as many graphs as you like that have $G$ as automorphism group.

Comment: @MorganRodgers, is there a rigorous proof that the automorphism group of the new graph will have $D_n$ as a subgroup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can define various *structures* such as graphs of valency $k$ (for some fixed $k \ge 3$), bipartite graphs, strongly regular graphs, $k$-chromatic graphs (for fixed $k \ge 2$), or $k$-connected graphs (fixed $k \ge 1$).  A structure $\mathcal{C}$ is said to be *universal* if every finite group is the automorphism group of some graph in $\mathcal{C}$.  Each of the structures just mentioned is known to be universal - this means that there exists at least one graph in each of these structures whose automorphism group is isomorphic to the dihedral group $D_n$ of order $2n$.

You can also consider Cayley graphs of the group $D_n$.  The automorphism group of a Cayley graph of $D_n$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $D_n$.

Comment: Could you point me to any reference for what you said about universal structures?

Comment: "Automorphisms of graphs" by Peter Cameron and the references therein.  A preprint version of this chapter survey is available online for download.